# Strange Object output in PHP when parsing JSON data sent by POST

Tags: php, json, apache2

I am a newbie with php and I aim to send JSON data from Particle Cloud (IoT cloud) to my Ubuntu 18.04 server with Apache2 and PHP7. I am writing php script that would parse JSON data but I have issues with accessing values of POSTed data

I have tried to follow different examples explaining how to convert `$_POST array` using `json_decode()` but I still have not figured out why it does not work

My file `data.json` is with JSON data

```
{"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}
```

my `parser.php` script is

```
<?php
$incoming = $_POST;
var_dump($incoming);

$data = json_decode(json_encode($var1), true);
var_dump($data);
?>
```

In Ubuntu 18.04 terminal I test dumped variables with curl

```
curl -v -X POST 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -d data.json http://localhost/parser.php
```

**My results**

```
for $incoming
    array(1){
    ["{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}"]=>
    string(0) ""
    }

for $data
    object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
    ["{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}"]=>
    string(0) ""
    }
```

But I expect something like `{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}`, not array or Object in []

I can't access values by keys. For example,

```
var_dump($data['key1']);
```

brings `NULL`

Comment: What is `$var1`?

Comment: Headers are sent with `--header`

Comment: and why are you encoding `$var1`, whatever that is?  (`json_decode(json_encode(`)

Comment: show the code used for  send the POST data

Comment: @scaisEdge data is sent with __cUrl request__.